# book for riemannian geometry

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry

I am looking for a book (a small book or course pdf or videos  ) for study the riemannian geometry
 for the beginning i need just  a basic understanding of Riemannian geometry

thank you for any suggestions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Beginner's book for Riemannian geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1546037/beginners-book-for-riemannian-geometry). Alternatively, see [Introductory text on Riemannian geometry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19505/introductory-text-on-riemannian-geometry).

Comment: see here http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~dnovikov/Manifolds5775/Chavel_Riemannian_Geometry_A_Modern_Intro.pdf

Comment: thank you for the suggestions